# Maximum sum of subsequence of length L with a restriction

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of positive integers. How to find a subsequence of length `L` with `max` sum which has the distance between any two of its neighboring elements that do not exceed `K`

I have the following solution but don't know how to take into account length L.

1 <= N <= 100000, 1 <= L <= 200, 1 <= K <= N

f[i] contains max sum of the subsequence that ends in i.

```
for i in range(K, N)
    f[i] = INT_MIN
    for j in range(1, K+1)
        f[i] = max(f[i], f[i-j] + a[i])
return max(f)
```

Comment: how is it 12 in the first example, when K is only 2? 10-1 is 9?

Comment: @ChristianSloper I think the "distance" refers to distance in element positions, not value differences (subsequences are not contiguous, see second example).

Comment: Can you add any constraints on length of array `N`, subsequence length `L` and distance `K`?

Comment: @Andreikkaa `1 <= N <= 100000, 1 <= L <= 200, 1 <= K <= N`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bottom up (ie no recursion) dynamic solution in Python.  It takes memory `O(l * n)` and time `O(l * n * k)`.

```
def max_subseq_sum(k, l, values):
    # table[i][j] will be the highest value from a sequence of length j
    # ending at position i
    table = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        # We have no sum from 0, and i from len 1.
        table.append([0, values[i]])
        # By length of previous subsequence
        for subseq_len in range(1, l):
            # We look back up to k for the best.
            prev_val = None
            for last_i in range(i-k, i):
                # We don't look back if the sequence was not that long.
                if subseq_len <= last_i+1:
                    # Is this better?
                    this_val = table[last_i][subseq_len]
                    if prev_val is None or prev_val < this_val:
                        prev_val = this_val
            # Do we have a best to offer?
            if prev_val is not None:
                table[i].append(prev_val + values[i])

    # Now we look for the best entry of length l.
    best_val = None
    for row in table:
        # If the row has entries for 0...l will have len > l.
        if l < len(row):
            if best_val is None or best_val < row[l]:
                best_val = row[l]
    return best_val

print(max_subseq_sum(2, 3, [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10]))
print(max_subseq_sum(3, 4, [8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 2, 5, 4]))
```

If I wanted to be slightly clever I could make this memory `O(n)` pretty easily by calculating one layer at a time, throwing away the previous one.  It takes a lot of cleverness to reduce running time to `O(l*n*log(k))` but that is doable.  (Use a priority queue for your best value in the last k.  It is `O(log(k))` to update it for each element but naturally grows.  Every `k` values you throw it away and rebuild it for a `O(k)` cost incurred `O(n/k)` times for a total `O(n)` rebuild cost.)

And here is the clever version.  Memory `O(n)`.  Time `O(n*l*log(k))` worst case, and average case is `O(n*l)`.  You hit the worst case when it is sorted in ascending order.

```
import heapq

def max_subseq_sum(k, l, values):
    count = 0
    prev_best = [0 for _ in values]
    # i represents how many in prev subsequences
    # It ranges from 0..(l-1).
    for i in range(l):
        # We are building subsequences of length i+1.
        # We will have no way to find one that ends
        # before the i'th element at position i-1
        best = [None for _ in range(i)]
        # Our heap will be (-sum, index).  It is a min_heap so the
        # minimum element has the largest sum.  We track the index
        # so that we know when it is in the last k.
        min_heap = [(-prev_best[i-1], i-1)]
        for j in range(i, len(values)):
            # Remove best elements that are more than k back.
            while min_heap[0][-1] < j-k:
                heapq.heappop(min_heap)

            # We append this value + (best prev sum) using -(-..) = +.
            best.append(values[j] - min_heap[0][0])
            heapq.heappush(min_heap, (-prev_best[j], j))

            # And now keep min_heap from growing too big.
            if 2*k < len(min_heap):
                # Filter out elements too far back.
                min_heap = [_ for _ in min_heap if j - k < _[1]]
                # And make into a heap again.
                heapq.heapify(min_heap)

        # And now finish this layer.
        prev_best = best
    return max(prev_best)
```

Comment: can you explain what your table represent? May be a line or two will help.

Comment: @newbie_old By construction, `table[i][j]` represents the largest sum of a subsequence of length `j` ending at position `i`.

Comment: I don't see the "throwing it away" pattern for the queue - how does that work? Say we're on L=2 traversal (K=4). I get to the 5th element and choose the best from the queue of 4. In the next iteration, wouldn't we want to keep 3 in the queue, remove the first and add the previous one? (I had in mind a tree and a list of pointers to keep track of which element to remove from the tree next.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן The queue is a priority queue.  Each element gets added.  They normally removed from the queue only when it is best and is older than `k`.  So over time the queue grows.  That would make it `O(l*n*log(n))`.  But if you preemptively clean out and rebuild the queue when it gets too long, then it winds up `O(l*n*log(k))` instead because the queue size now remains `O(k)`.  I'll add code for that to make the idea make more sense.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added the clever version.  Hopefully you will see what I mean about "cleaning out".  Amusingly, the code wound up simpler as well.

Answer (score 5):

(edit: slightly simplified non-recursive solution)

You can do it like this, just for each iteration consider if the item should be included or excluded.

```
def f(maxK,K, N, L, S):
    if L == 0 or not N or K == 0:
        return S
    #either element is included
    included = f(maxK,maxK, N[1:], L-1, S + N[0]  )
    #or excluded
    excluded = f(maxK,K-1, N[1:], L, S )
    return max(included, excluded)


assert f(2,2,[10,1,1,1,1,10],3,0) == 12
assert f(3,3,[8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 2, 5, 4],4,0) == 30
```

If N is very long you can consider changing to a table version, you could also change the input to tuples and use memoization.

Since OP later included the information that N can be 100 000, we can't really use recursive solutions like this.  So here is a solution that runs in O(n*K*L), with same memory requirement:

```
import numpy as np

def f(n,K,L):
    t = np.zeros((len(n),L+1))

    for l in range(1,L+1):
        for i in range(len(n)):
            t[i,l] = n[i] + max( (t[i-k,l-1] for k in range(1,K+1) if i-k >= 0), default = 0 )

    return np.max(t)


assert f([10,1,1,1,1,10],2,3) == 12
assert f([8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9],3,4) == 30
```

Explanation of the non recursive solution.  Each cell in the table t[ i, l ] expresses the value of max subsequence with exactly l elements that use the element in position i and only elements in position i or lower where elements have at most K distance between each other.

subsequences of length n (those in t[i,1] have to have only one element, n[i] )

Longer subsequences have the n[i] + a subsequence of l-1 elements that starts at most k rows earlier, we pick the one with the maximal value. By iterating this way, we ensure that this value is already calculated.

Further improvements in memory is possible by considering that you only look at most K steps back.

Comment: the size of the array is N <= 100000

Comment: Then you definitely need to go to a table version.. recursion depth will kill you.

Comment: could you please write a non-recursive solution?

Comment: @ChristianSloper: can you explain your non recursive solution?

Comment: @newbie_old added an explanation of the on recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the code for `itertools.combinations` shown at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), I built a version that includes an argument for the maximum index distance (`K`) between two values. It only needed an additional `and indices[i] - indices[i-1] < K` check in the iteration:

```
def combinations_with_max_dist(iterable, r, K):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r and indices[i] - indices[i-1] < K:
                break
        else:
            return               
        indices[i] += 1        
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Using this you can bruteforce over all combinations with regards to K, and then find the one that has the maximum value sum:

```
def find_subseq(a, L, K):
    return max((sum(values), values) for values in combinations_with_max_dist(a, L, K))
```

Results:

```
print(*find_subseq([10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10], L=3, K=2))
# 12 (10, 1, 1)
print(*find_subseq([8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 2, 5, 4], L=4, K=3))
# 30 (8, 7, 6, 9)
```

Not sure about the performance if your value lists become very long though...

Comment: the length of list is <= 100000

Answer (score 1):

---

### Algorithm

**Basic idea:**

- **Iteration** on input array, choose each index as the first taken element.
- Then **Recursion** on each first taken element, mark the index as `firstIdx`.

  - The next possible index would be in range `[firstIdx + 1, firstIdx + K]`, both inclusive.
  - Loop on the range to call each index recursively, with `L - 1` as the new L.
- Optionally, for each pair of (`firstIndex`, `L`), **cache** its max sum, for reuse.
  Maybe this is necessary for large input.

**Constraints**:

- `array length` <= `1 << 17` // `131072`
- `K` <= `1 << 6` // `64`
- `L` <= `1 << 8` // `256`

**Complexity:**

- **Time:** `O(n * L * K)`
  Since each `(firstIdx , L)` pair only calculated once, and that contains a iteration of `K.`
- **Space**:  `O(n * L)`
  For cache, and method stack in recursive call.

**Tips:**

- Depth of recursion is related to `L`, ***not*** `array length`.
- The defined constraints are not the actual limit, it could be larger, though I didn't test how large it can be.
  Basically:

  - Both `array length` and `K` actually could be of any size as long as there are enough memory, since they are handled via iteration.
  - `L` is handled via recursion, thus it does has a limit.

---

### Code - in `Java`

**SubSumLimitedDistance.java:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SubSumLimitedDistance {
    public static final long NOT_ENOUGH_ELE = -1; // sum that indicate not enough element, should be < 0,
    public static final int MAX_ARR_LEN = 1 << 17; // max length of input array,
    public static final int MAX_K = 1 << 6; // max K, should not be too long, otherwise slow,
    public static final int MAX_L = 1 << 8; // max L, should not be too long, otherwise stackoverflow,

    /**
     * Find max sum of sum array.
     *
     * @param arr
     * @param K
     * @param L
     * @return max sum,
     */
    public static long find(int[] arr, int K, int L) {
        if (K < 1 || K > MAX_K)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("K should be between [1, " + MAX_K + "], but get: " + K);
        if (L < 0 || L > MAX_L)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("L should be between [0, " + MAX_L + "], but get: " + L);
        if (arr.length > MAX_ARR_LEN)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input array length should <= " + MAX_ARR_LEN + ", but get: " + arr.length);

        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> cache = new HashMap<>(); // cache,

        long maxSum = NOT_ENOUGH_ELE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            long sum = findTakeFirst(arr, K, L, i, cache);
            if (sum == NOT_ENOUGH_ELE) break; // not enough elements,

            if (sum > maxSum) maxSum = sum; // larger found,
        }

        return maxSum;
    }

    /**
     * Find max sum of sum array, with index of first taken element specified,
     *
     * @param arr
     * @param K
     * @param L
     * @param firstIdx index of first taken element,
     * @param cache
     * @return max sum,
     */
    private static long findTakeFirst(int[] arr, int K, int L, int firstIdx, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> cache) {
        // System.out.printf("findTakeFirst(): K = %d, L = %d, firstIdx = %d\n", K, L, firstIdx);
        if (L == 0) return 0; // done,
        if (firstIdx + L > arr.length) return NOT_ENOUGH_ELE; // not enough elements,

        // check cache,
        Map<Integer, Long> map = cache.get(firstIdx);
        Long cachedResult;
        if (map != null && (cachedResult = map.get(L)) != null) {
            // System.out.printf("hit cache, cached result = %d\n", cachedResult);
            return cachedResult;
        }

        // cache not exists, calculate,
        long maxRemainSum = NOT_ENOUGH_ELE;
        for (int i = firstIdx + 1; i <= firstIdx + K; i++) {
            long remainSum = findTakeFirst(arr, K, L - 1, i, cache);
            if (remainSum == NOT_ENOUGH_ELE) break; // not enough elements,
            if (remainSum > maxRemainSum) maxRemainSum = remainSum;
        }

        if ((map = cache.get(firstIdx)) == null) cache.put(firstIdx, map = new HashMap<>());

        if (maxRemainSum == NOT_ENOUGH_ELE) { // not enough elements,
            map.put(L, NOT_ENOUGH_ELE); // cache - as not enough elements,
            return NOT_ENOUGH_ELE;
        }

        long maxSum = arr[firstIdx] + maxRemainSum; // max sum,
        map.put(L, maxSum); // cache - max sum,

        return maxSum;
    }
}
```

**SubSumLimitedDistanceTest.java:**
*(test case, via `TestNG`)*

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class SubSumLimitedDistanceTest {
    private int[] arr;
    private int K;
    private int L;
    private int maxSum;

    private int[] arr2;
    private int K2;
    private int L2;
    private int maxSum2;

    private int[] arrMax;
    private int KMax;
    private int KMaxLargest;

    private int LMax;
    private int LMaxLargest;

    @BeforeClass
    private void setUp() {
        // init - arr,
        arr = new int[]{10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10};
        K = 2;
        L = 3;
        maxSum = 12;

        // init - arr2,
        arr2 = new int[]{8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 2, 5, 4};
        K2 = 3;
        L2 = 4;
        maxSum2 = 30;

        // init - arrMax,
        arrMax = new int[SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_ARR_LEN];
        ThreadLocalRandom rd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        long maxLongEle = Long.MAX_VALUE / SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_ARR_LEN;
        int maxEle = maxLongEle > Integer.MAX_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : (int) maxLongEle;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrMax.length; i++) {
            arrMax[i] = rd.nextInt(maxEle);
        }

        KMax = 5;
        LMax = 10;

        KMaxLargest = SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_K;
        LMaxLargest = SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_L;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(arr, K, L), maxSum);
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(arr2, K2, L2), maxSum2);
    }

    @Test(timeOut = 6000)
    public void test_veryLargeArray() {
        run_printDuring(arrMax, KMax, LMax);
    }

    @Test(timeOut = 60000) // takes seconds,
    public void test_veryLargeArrayL() {
        run_printDuring(arrMax, KMax, LMaxLargest);
    }

    @Test(timeOut = 60000) // takes seconds,
    public void test_veryLargeArrayK() {
        run_printDuring(arrMax, KMaxLargest, LMax);
    }

    // run find once, and print during,
    private void run_printDuring(int[] arr, int K, int L) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long sum = SubSumLimitedDistance.find(arr, K, L);
        long during = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; // during in milliseconds,
        System.out.printf("arr length = %5d, K = %3d, L = %4d, max sum = %15d, running time = %.3f seconds\n", arr.length, K, L, sum, during / 1000.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_corner_notEnoughEle() {
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1}, 2, 3), SubSumLimitedDistance.NOT_ENOUGH_ELE); // not enough element,
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{0}, 1, 3), SubSumLimitedDistance.NOT_ENOUGH_ELE); // not enough element,
    }

    @Test
    public void test_corner_ZeroL() {
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 2, 0), 0); // L = 0,
        Assert.assertEquals(SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{0}, 1, 0), 0); // L = 0,
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void test_invalid_K() {
        // SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 0, 2); // K = 0,
        // SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, -1, 2); // K = -1,
        SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_K + 1, 2); // K = SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_K+1,
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void test_invalid_L() {
        // SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 2, -1); // L = -1,
        SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, 2, SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_L + 1); // L = SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_L+1,
    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void test_invalid_tooLong() {
        SubSumLimitedDistance.find(new int[SubSumLimitedDistance.MAX_ARR_LEN + 1], 2, 3); // input array too long,
    }
}
```

**Output of test case for large input:**

```
arr length = 131072, K =   5, L =   10, max sum =     20779205738, running time = 0.303 seconds
arr length = 131072, K =  64, L =   10, max sum =     21393422854, running time = 1.917 seconds
arr length = 131072, K =   5, L =  256, max sum =    461698553839, running time = 9.474 seconds
```

Comment: No, your complexity is `O(NKL)`, it does not depend on cache. You call your function exactly `K` times inside loop, and number of function states is `O(NL)`.